# PHP redirect link only updates sql database once every minute

Tags: php, sql

For tracking the number of clicks (and IP) for a website I created a php script that stores the date and IP info and only once the query was executed successfully it redirects the user to the link. Even though the following script is very minimal, it works.

However, if I click the link twice within one minute (tested both in Chrome and Edge) it does not save this as a click but it does redirect me to the correct page which I find very odd. I have tried this by clicking multiple times and only the values after +-1 min get stored.

Opening a new Chrome window does not work. Opening an incognito screen within 1 min does work and this click gets saved.

Addition info: in the SQL database there is a primary ID column with AUTO_INCREMENT.

**Question**: is there any reason why this happens (perhaps caching?) and would there be any way to prevent this?

The URL to redirect to link 1 is: *thisphpfile.php?link=1*

```
//---------
// Get info on which link to point to
$link = $_GET["link"];

// Check link value to prevent SQL injection
if($link =='1'){
    $link_sql = "https://www.url1.com";
}
if($link =='2'){
    $link_sql = "https://www.url2.com";
}
    


// If link was a valid input, continue, else back to homepage
if($link =='1' || $link == '2'){


$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (DATE , IP, LINK) VALUES ('$date', '$ip','$link_sql')";

//Execute query
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
ob_end_flush();

// Redirect link
header("Location: " . $link_sql);
}

}else{
    // Redirect link
    header("Location: https://www.default.com" );
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, why you change the location in either case? Shouldn't that script just get executed (without redirection)? And the condition just checks, if the insert worked. And it actually should. Enable `ini_set('display_errors', true)` and check the errors. Try `$conn->errorInfo():` too.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction on how to both redirect the user and execute the php file?

Comment: you say "if I click the link twice within one minute it does not save this as a click but it does redirect me to the correct page" so maybe you have resaved one row? Need table structure to see more.. also check seconds of created_at and updated_at (if not implamant this recommend do this)

Comment: DATE column is a varchar which includes seconds. Even if it was the same, it should add the new row with INSERT and not overwrite the row.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Also, be warned that your query is widely open for SQL injection - please have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: Can you please show us the way you initialize your connection to the database? So I can update my answer to be more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following fixed the issue:

```
    // Redirect link
header('HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Location: ' . $link_sql, true, 307);
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't see the reason, why it shouldn't get saved. But your code structure is a little bit unclear. Maybe you can try it with the following code and we can work it out somehow:

```
$links = [
    1 => 'https://www.url1.com',
    2 => 'https://www.url2.com'
];

// Check if GET-parameter is numeric and if the number is in the links array above
if (is_numeric($_GET["link"]) && isset($links[intval($_GET["link"])])) {
    $link = $links[intval($_GET["link"])];

    $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO tablename (DATE, IP, LINK) values ('%s', '%s', '%s')",
        date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        $link
    );

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        header("Location: " . $link);
        exit;
    }
}

// This will be the default header when the exit above cannot be reached (because of errors)
header("Location: https://www.default.com");
```

Comment: `sprintf` should never be used to build SQL queries

Comment: Why? It is a save query because no user input is directly inserted into the database. But he could of course use parameters of PDO for this.

Comment: There's no reason to distinguish between "safe" queries that are allowed to use such insecure ways. **All** queries should be designed to be safe

Comment: What is unsafe about sprintf? I cannot find any information about this.

Comment: Whatever you use as an argument can be unsafe, for example if any of the links is later exchanged by a link containing special chars, or if the list of arguments is extended to other parts. Once more, there's no good reason to not use prepared statements from the beginning, especially to get trained and to fade out any old programming styles